# Dell U2312HM (DP) + Intel HD 3000 = Flicker

Tags: displayport

I'm using a Dell U2312HM monitor with my Lenovo X220 (Intel HD 3000 graphics card) via DisplayPort at work. Sadly, there is an issue with this combination: The Dell flickers once in a while. It's only a short flicker but working with the Combo for 8 hours (I'm a programmer) still makes it annoying. There is no "rythm" to it, it just randomly flickers. Sometimes 5 minutes between the flickers, sometimes it's 20 or more.

Switching the VGA driver for newer or older ones didn't help. Switching to VGA cable helps but the picture is not as fine as the DP one, that's why I want to use it.

Comment: If it was something generic, like an inverter, it would happen regardless of the connection.  But, that's an LED monitor, so there isn't even an inverter.  It *could* be one or two LEDs causing the flicker... but that still wouldn't explain why it only happens on the DP.  Any chance it is another device on the network at work?  I've seen network printers that cause screens to blank momentarily.  Not every computer on the network either.  Can you change the DP cable?  Examine the port on the laptop?

Comment: I can try and test the cable on my colleagues laptop and monitor and also test my notebook on his monitor (same make). I don't think it's a LED that casues the flicker because - as you said - with VGA everything is ok.

Comment: See [this page](https://communities.intel.com/thread/30096?start=105&tstart=0). In brief, to fix this you either have to remove all but one RAM modules, or (better) update motherboard BIOS.

Comment: Related question: https://superuser.com/q/489931/470